# MySQL #1100 - Table 'USER' was not locked with LOCK TABLES

Tags: mysql

I am having a very strange problem. I have developed a database and it works perfectly on my local server however then I tried to put it online on my server I keep getting MySQL error:

```
#1100 - Table 'USER' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
```

(This is then I try to import my .sql file via phpMyAdmin)

Once again this same script gives no errors on my local server (WAMP server)

I have no Idea why it does not work then I try to put it online. Also it creates the tables and structure the problem is only with the insert statements.

SQL script:

```
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=''*/;

/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/`a3823833_MiniPos` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;

USE `a3823833_MiniPos`;

/*Table structure for table `user` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;

CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `userid` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Table structure for table `profile` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `profile`;

CREATE TABLE `profile` (
  `userid` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(50),
  `firstName` varchar(50),
  `dob` varchar(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`),
  CONSTRAINT `profile_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `user` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Table structure for table 'topic'*/

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `topic`;

CREATE TABLE `topic` (
    `topicid` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `userid` int(4) NOT NULL,
    `text` varchar(2000),
    `time` datetime,
    PRIMARY KEY (`topicid`),
    CONSTRAINT `userid_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `user` (`userid`)
 )  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/* Table structure for table 'post'*/

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `post`;

CREATE TABLE `post` (
    `postid` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `topicid` int(4),
    `userid` int(4) NOT NULL,
    `text` varchar(2000),
    `time` datetime,
    PRIMARY KEY (`postid`),
    CONSTRAINT `post_userid_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `user` (`userid`),
    CONSTRAINT `post_topicid_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`topicid`) REFERENCES `topic` (`topicid`)
)   ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



LOCK TABLES `user` WRITE;
INSERT INTO USER VALUES (1,'Martynas','MartynPass','Martyn@email.com'),(2,'Syed','SyedPass','Syed@email.com'),(3,'Stephanie','StephPass','Steph@email.com');
UNLOCK TABLES;
LOCK TABLES `topic` WRITE;
INSERT INTO topic VALUES (1, 1,'Topic Number 1','2015-06-11 20:15:00'),(2, 2,'Topic Number 2','2015-06-10 19:15:00'),(3, 3,'Topic Number 3','2015-06-09 18:15:00');
UNLOCK TABLES;
LOCK TABLES `post` WRITE;
INSERT INTO post VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'Very Interesting Topic Number 1','2015-06-11 20:15:00'),(2, 1, 2, 'Agree!','2015-06-11 21:15:00');
UNLOCK TABLES;
```